# C++ указатели

Tags: c++

Добрый день, недавно начал изучать С++, дошел до указателей, почитал на разных форумах про них и понял что в общем штука важная.
Прошу перечислить где их разумно применять(ну или где без них не обойтись);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Указатели применяют:

1. Для возврата нескольких значений из функции. В качестве аргумента передаётся указатель на переменную, функция записывает туда значение. Такой подход очень распространён в DirectX. Для этого можно использовать и ссылки, но не рекомендуется, так как синтаксис передачи и возврата неотличим.
2. Для хранения адреса динамически выделенной памяти. Она отличается от обычной тем, что программист сам регулирует время жизни объектов, и её больше (а размер стека всего примерно 1 МБ). Если адрес будет потерян, то память нельзя будет ни использовать, ни освободить. Возникнет утечка памяти.
3. C-строка представляет собой указатель на её первый символ.
4. Для создания всяких структур типа связанных списков.
5. Для передачи аргумента в функцию без копирования, которое может оказаться долгим для сложных объектов. Правда, здесь лучше использовать константные ссылки.

Это я ещё наверное не всё перечислил. Примений указателей очень много.

Comment: Вот для масивов указывают адрес 0 эл -та? для чего это?Весь массив хранится в ячейке памяти или отдельный элемент в отдельной ячейке?

Comment: Ячейка памяти - 1 байт. Естественно что например массив целых чисел хранится более чем в одной ячейке. Для массива указывается *адрес начала массива*, фактически это адрес его первого элемента. В функции как правило передается только этот адрес, так как массив может быть достаточно большим, а копировать массив целиком может быть довольно накладно.